# getJSON Jquery was working in jQuery 1.2.3 and now on v1.5.1 throwing parse error

Tags: jquery, getjson

I have been using this PHP script for a long time and this is returning data to my getJSON . I changed to jquery new version v1.5.1  from  1.2.3  Today  and giving parse error

```
  <?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 0);
include("conndb.php");

    function createoptions($table , $id , $field , $condition_field , $value)
    {
        $sql = sprintf("select * from $table WHERE $condition_field=%d ORDER BY $field" , $value);
        $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {
            while ($a = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
            $out[] = "{optionValue: {$a[$id]}, optionDisplay: '$a[$field]'}";
            return "[" . implode("," , $out) . "]";
        } else

            return "[{optionValue: -1 , optionDisplay: 'No result'}]";
    }

    if (isset($_GET['country'])) {
        echo createoptions("state" , "state_id" , "state" , "country_id" , $_GET['country']);
    }


    if (isset($_GET['state'])) {
        echo createoptions("city" , "city_id" , "city" , "state_id" , $_GET['state']);
    }

    die();
    ?>
```

My getJson code

```
$.getJSON("select_old.php",{country: '$(this).val()', ajax: 'true'}, function(j){
                  var options = '';
                  for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
                    options += '<option value="' + j[i].optionValue + '">' + j[i].optionDisplay + '</option>';
                    if( i==0){
                     populateCity(j[i].optionValue );
                    }
                  }
                  $("select#state").html(options);
                }).error(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {  alert(xhr.statusText); })
```

Thanks for your help

Regards

Kiran

Comment: What's the error message? Is it from PHP or JavaScript? Also, you should use [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) instead of building your own JSON strings.

Comment: Am I confused or is your query string actually `select_old.php?country=$(this).val()&ajax=true` Are you sure you want the `$(this).val()` to be a string?

Comment: This may also be caused by the stricter JSON parser jQuery > 1.4 uses - check your JSON's validity here: http://www.jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{country: '$(this).val()', ajax: 'true'}
```

This should probably be

```
var country = $(this).val();

$.getJSON("select_old.php", { country: country, ajax: 'true' }, function(j) {
```

**Edit:** Also, see my comment above regarding `json_encode()` - example

```
$data = array();
while ($a = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $data[] = array(
        'optionValue'   => $a[$id],
        'optionDisplay' => $a[$field]
    );
}
return json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Thanks Phil , But unfortunately.. this change didn't work . Could you point me how to use  json_encode() for my case .

Comment: @YiJiang You sure about that? My (Firefox) tests indicate otherwise

Comment: This is the data format [{optionValue: 283, optionDisplay: 'Belize'},{optionValue: 284, optionDisplay: 'Cayo'},{optionValue: 285, optionDisplay: 'Corozal'},{optionValue: 286, optionDisplay: 'Orange Walk'},{optionValue: 287, optionDisplay: 'Toledo'}]

Comment: or on top do I need to mention any json header ?  as I said It was working perfect with old version ..

Comment: @PhilBrown Right, stupid mistake. Keys are always evaluated as strings

Comment: @Bujji It couldn't hurt. Use `header('Content-Type: application/json')` before you `echo` the data

Comment: I used json_encode and it did the magic now the data is coming back to my getJson function , But after getting the array j[0] has this value "{optionValue: 2771, optionDisplay: 'Banjul'}" . How do I get optionValue , when I tried j[0].optionValue  it says "Undefined"

Comment: @Bujji Add a breakpoint (Firebug JS debugger for example) at the first line of your callback function and inspect `j`, making sure it is indeed a JSON array of `{optionValue, optionDisplay}` objects

Comment: Thanks Phil for your help . I see it is coming as array , but inside array it is string ( I think) . The result is like this It is coming as ["{optionValue: 283, optionDisplay: 'Belize'}","{optionValue: 284, optionDisplay: 'Cayo'}","{optionValue: 285, optionDisplay: 'Corozal'}","{optionValue: 286, optionDisplay: 'Orange Walk'}","{optionValue: 287, optionDisplay: 'Toledo'}"]  . So the "" quotes are treating it as string ..? any solution

Comment: @Bujji I think you've added JSON strings into `json_encode()`. Check out the example in my answer (latest edit)

Comment: Thank You Phil for your help . I am able to resolve this issue with your help .